# Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sequelize' of module exports inside circular dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, nodemon

**Problem**

```
nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.15

[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`

[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*

[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json

[nodemon] starting `node server.js`

Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.     
(node:11528) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sequelize' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Server running at port: 8000
```

***It can run the website normally.
But how can I fix it?***

**ps. every time you run The numbers are unique. --> (node:11528)**

**Other problems**

**When i use --> "node --trace-warnings sequelize"**

```
PS C:\Users\company\Desktop\Project> node --trace-warnings sequelize
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\company\Desktop\Project\sequelize'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

**When i use --> "nodemon -e js,ejs index.js"**

```
[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,ejs
[nodemon] starting `node index.js index.js`
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\company\Desktop\Project\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

***"node --trace-warnings sequelize" and "nodemon -e js,ejs index.js" : The website cannot run normally. But how can I fix it?***

Node : v16.13.1
Sequelize : v6.12.4
Nodemon : v2.0.15
DB : mySQL

**code server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const appRoutes = require('./routes')

const { sequelize } = require("./models")

const appSchedule = require("./schedules")

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');


app.use(cookieParser("secret"));

//config session
app.use(session({
   secret: 'secret',
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: false,
   cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 // 86400000 = 1 day
   }
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//Config passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    
    // static resources
    app.use(`/public/`, express.static('public'))

    // ejs view
    app.set('views', 'views')
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

    // app route
    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(express.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }))
    app.use(`/`, appRoutes)

    // start schedule
    appSchedule.start()
    // listen connection
    app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Server running at port: ${process.env.PORT}`)
    })    
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
})
```

**It's the first question. If there is any mistake, I apologize at this point.**

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues

1. When you run `--trace-warnings`, you are pointing to a non-existent file. You need to run it on the same file, e.g. `node --trace-warnings server.js`.
2. The nodemon call suffers from a similar issue, you could try `nodemon -e js,ejs server.js` and see what the output is
3. This is the line causing you issues. The error indicates that `sequelize` is not exported as from this file. Perhaps you meant `const sequelize = require('./models')`? You'd have to include the code from `./models` to be sure

```js
const { sequelize } = require("./models")
```

Comment: 3. This is the line causing you issues. The error indicates that sequelize is not exported as from this file. Perhaps you meant const sequelize = require('./models')? You'd have to include the code from ./models to be sure


**Thank you for reminding me.

I found that some code snippets are being used differently from the other files, I have removed that line. so now it doesn't show up anymore (The error is in the models file somewhere.) thank you very much**

Comment: 2.The nodemon call suffers from a similar issue, you could try nodemon -e js,ejs server.js and see what the output is

**It works, thanks.**

Comment: 1.When you run --trace-warnings, you are pointing to a non-existent file. You need to run it on the same file, e.g. node --trace-warnings server.js.

**Ok, now I understand how to use it. Thank you very much for the advice. Really appreciate it.**

Answer (score 1):

I  discovered that the arrangement had no effect in the error, I tweaked the Javascript destructuring when I was calling the function in another file and it magically solved the problem.

I changed the top of server.js

from:

```
const { sequelize } = require("./models")
```

to:

```
const model = require("./models")
```

And at the point where you want to call the function , then you can do this:

```
model.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

> Circular dependency is forbidden in nodejs

In my case, what was actually happening that my controller was containing a function that I created for the sake of re-usability and then I started creating such functions in a file named helpers... later on I was importing those functions from the helpers file but there was this one function I was importing from my controller to my helpers file... That caused a circular dependency... In short my controller was using a function from helpers and the helpers was using a function from my controller.

**What worked for me?**

I just moved my helper function from my controller to my helpers file and it sorted out the issue...